# How can I rephrase "I will want to break work and will be free"?

Tags: phrase-request

I need short phrase to say "I will want to quit work, will create own business and will be free."
How can I rephrase that sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a common way of saying this (at least in the U.S.) is:

> *I want to be my own boss.*

If you [Google the phrase](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22be%20your%20own%20boss%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t), you can see that it's commonly used in articles and blogs.

The phrase "be your own boss" is commonly used when recruiting people into certain businesses or [educational programs](http://www.clevelandcc.edu/entrepreneurship.php).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The buzzword in business circles for the last ten or fifteen years has been

> I want to become an **entrepreneur**.